# Elasticsearch routing and wildcard

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, routes

When using Elasticsearch with manual routing (providing the routing value directly in the http query when indexing a document), I have troubles trying to retrieve the document with its ID if there is wildcard in the routing value.

For example, if I index a document with the ID "Arya" with this query (`myRouting` as routing value, note the uppercase character):

```
curl -XPOST 'http://elasticsearch:9200/xxxx/yyyy/Arya?routing=myRouting' -d @dataset/arya_simple.json
```

When I try to query the cluster, using a wildcard as the routing value, no document is returned:

```
curl -XGET 'http://elasticsearch:9200/xxxx/yyyy/Arya?routing=*'
```

The answer is `{"_index":"xxxx","_type":"yyyy","_id":"Arya","found":false}`

On the other hand, if I use a routing value that has no uppercase character in it (`myrouting` as the routing value, no uppercase character):

```
curl -XPOST 'http://elasticsearch:9200/xxxx/yyyy/Arya?routing=myrouting' -d @dataset/arya_simple.json
```

(`myrouting` instead of `myRouting`)

It works, and the same GET request as I just did gives me the document:

```
curl -XGET 'http://elasticsearch:9200/xxxx/yyyy/Arya?routing=*'

{"_index":"xxxx","_type":"yyyy","_id":"Arya","_version":1,"found":true,"_source":{ ... .... }}
```

Do you have any idea why the wildcard is only working when no uppercase in the routing value ?

If I provide `*Routing` as a routing value when performing GET, I also get the document.

It seems that wildcard is stopping at the first uppercased character...

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, routing does not work that way. You can't specify wildcard routing and expect it to somehow magically find your document. If thats your intent, you can perform a search request on the id field of the document. As far as elastic is concerned, routing=* is just another routing value. The fact that routing=* and routing=Routing results in similar behavior in your case, may be attributed to luck, or your cluster environment, for example, how many shards do you have?  If you don't have many shards, its more likely that different routing values will hit the same shard.

Comment: Thank you Roman ! Indeed, this cluster is a test cluster that only has 5 shards, so it is more likely that the two routing values were hitting the same shard...

Comment: However, I have no document with a routing value `*`, I thought that since Elasticsearch doesn't know the routing value `*`, it would search against all shards and documents, no matter their routing value.

Comment: You probably know by now, but just for posterity: No, there's no concept of "known" and "unknown" routing values. Any routing string will simply hash to some shard, so in your cluster it sounds like the strings `*` and `Routing` happened to hash to the same shard.